# linqTOsql returning a "specified cast not valid" exception at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have two linqTOsql entities that has a parent and child relationship, one to many. I'm running into an issue that when I retrieve the parent record, I am unable to loop through the related records in the child table.

This code fails:

```
    public string test()
    { 
        string output;
        StreamEntry entry = genesisRepository.StreamEntries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.seID == 6);

        output = entry.seUrl.ToString() + "<br />";
        foreach(var item in entry.FieldInstance)
        {

            output = "<ul>";
            output += "<li>" + item.fiLabel.ToString() + "</li>";
            output = "</ul>";
        }
        return output;
    }
```

The error is:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Source Error: 


Line 230:            
Line 231:            output = entry.seUrl.ToString() + "<br />";
Line 232:            foreach(var item in entry.FieldInstance)
Line 233:            {
Line 234:                


Source File: C:\pathtoscript.cs    Line: 232 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +5002837
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i) +38
   Read_FieldInstance(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +1993
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +32
   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.Load() +124
   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.GetEnumerator() +13
```

I don't understand why the stacktrace is showing `int32`. I'm 99% certain that I have been using `long` and `bigint` for all my IDs. Just to cover all my bases, heres the parent and child model code:

Parent:

```
[Table]
public class StreamEntry
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public long seID { get; set; }

    /* other fields removed for brevity  */

    // relationship (one entry to many FieldInstances) 
    // uses EntitySet<FieldInstance> and OtherKey for the FK in FieldInstance 
    // which is the "Other" table.
    private EntitySet<FieldInstance> _FieldInstance = new EntitySet<FieldInstance>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_FieldInstance", OtherKey = "fiStreamEntryID")]
    public EntitySet<FieldInstance> FieldInstance
    {
        get { return this._FieldInstance; }
        set { this._FieldInstance.Assign(value); }
    }

}
```

Child:

```
[Table]
public class FieldInstance
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public long fiID { get; set; }

   /* Other field removed for brevity */ 

    [Column]
    public long fiStreamEntryID { get; set; }  // FK

    // Relationship (many FieldInstances to one StreamEntry)
    // using EntityRef<StreamEntry> and ThisKey
    // which is "This" table's FK
    private EntityRef<StreamEntry> _StreamEntry;
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_StreamEntry", ThisKey = "fiStreamEntryID")]
    public StreamEntry StreamEntry
    {
        get { return this._StreamEntry.Entity; }
        set { this._StreamEntry.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

What could be causing my cast exception?

### Edit - adding table definitions

> StreamEntry Table:
>
> seID bigint notnull
>
> seUrl nvarchar(255) notnull
>
> seHeadline nvarchar(255) notnull
>
> seBody ntext nullable
>
> seDescription nvarchar(255) nullable
>
> seKeywords nvarchar(255) nullable
>
> seTitle nvarchar(255) nullable
>
> seOrder bigint notnull
>
> seDateCreated datetime notnull
>
> seDateModified datetime notnull
>
> StreamID bigint notnull
>
> AllowComents bit notnull

FieldInstance Table:

> ftID bigint notnull
>
> ftIsRequired bit notnull
>
> ftLabel nvarchar(50) notnull
>
> ftStrValue nvarchar(1000) nullable
>
> ftDateTimeValue datetime nullable
>
> ftIntValue int nullable
>
> ftDecValue decimal(18,0) nullable
>
> ftOrder bigint notnull
>
> ftStreamEntryID bigint notnull  --- FK to StreamEntry table
>
> ftFieldTypeID bigint notbull

### Edit - Added StreamEntry Record

This code:

```
   public string test()
    { 
        string output;
        StreamEntry entry = genesisRepository.StreamEntries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.seID == 6);

        output = entry.seID.ToString() + "<br />";
        output += entry.seUrl + "<br />";
        output += entry.seHeadline + "<br />";
        output += entry.seBody + "<br />";
        output += entry.seDescription + "<br />";
        output += entry.seKeywords + "<br />";
        output += entry.seTitle + "<br />";
        output += entry.seOrder.ToString() + "<br />";
        output += entry.seDateCreated.ToString() + "<br />";
        output += entry.seDateModified.ToString() + "<br />";
        output += entry.StreamID.ToString() + "<br />";
        output += entry.AllowComments.ToString() + "<br />";

        return output;
    }
```

Returns:

> 6
>
> asd
>
> asd

>

>

>

>

> 0
>
> 2010-11-16 4:10:45 PM
>
> 2010-11-16 4:10:45 PM
>
> 75
>
> False

Comment: @Abe - no. It's set as non-nullable, bigint, Auto-increment identity

Comment: Can you add the table definition as well?

Comment: Can post the record that is returned for `StreamEntry entry = .. `

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @Anders - will edit question for table definitions

Comment: @Abe - see edited question for `StreamEntry` record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you updated the column type in your underlying database without updating your DBML?

Comment: No. I posted both my `StreamEntry` and FieldInstance` table definition in my question. The types match.

Comment: Doggonit--- I think I may have found it. One sec while I try to recompile

Comment: I don't have a DBML.. I am just defining my table using classes... but I did have two fields set to int that shoulda been long and vice versa